# What's the maximum amount of damage you can take to keep an A?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

Hey just wondering how much damage you can take before getting a B in Hyrule Warriors

Comment: I believe that it differs from map to map.

Comment: Other factors are involved in getting higher ranks (enemies killed, time taken, deaths) and all of them change based on the level.  It may even change based on difficulty, but I'm not sure on that one.

Answer (score 4):

In order to get an A ranking you need to meet the following criteria:

```
Damage - take less then 4,000 damage ( 10 hearts )
KOs - 1,200 or more
Time - 15 minutes or less
```

Now this does change depending on the level, some levels have required times to beat to get an A,  in this case just beat them under the time limit by 3 minutes.

**Example**

Defeat 300 enemies in 10 minutes.

```
Damage - take less than 4,000 damage (10 hearts)
Time - 7 minutes or less
```

Comment: Where did you happen to get this information?  What levels are different?

Comment: It is almost universal with a few specific exceptions.

Comment: There are a few levels where it differs, which I cannot list right now as the game isn't in front of me. This information stems from the good old, tried and true method, which I call player testing.

Comment: This doesn't match my experiences with the game at all.  I haven't seen a single level require less than seven minutes yet.

Comment: Oh that was just an arbitrary example to think of on the fly just to hammer in the point I was making above the example. Also, 7 minutes or less would be to get an A ranking in that example.

Comment: That 7 minutes one is an outlier specific to the kill X enemies levels. 10 minute time limits you need 7 or less for A rank (might be 7:30 or 8 but 7 sounds right). 60 minute maps are typically 15 minutes or less for A rank. 90% of maps are 60 minute time limits. This is as right an answer you can get without listing every single levels requirements. (again 90% of which will just be the first set of criteria over and over again.)

Comment: Some of the later levels also have much more generous damage limits, to compensate somewhat for the much higher damage you take.